# UIImageView and UIButton mess image after screen rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, uikit

I'm trying to make container with arrow. Container is `UIView`, arrow is `UIImageView` that positioning opposite to the parent center.

I created a 'popover' with button with background image and added an arrow. It works just fine.

[image: all is ok]

You see that rectangle sides are sharp.

Ok, let's rotate.

[image: mess 1]

WAT. Rotate again...

[image: mess 2]

Images are scaled. And even that resizing isn't constant. But all frames are ok.

Before rotation

```
2013-04-18 21:20:41.198 Project[15790:907] 
conta: {{124, 313}, {200, 49}}
content: {{0, 9}, {200, 40}}
arrow: {{87, 0}, {19, 9}}
```

After rotation

```
2013-04-18 21:22:06.717 Project[15790:907] 
container: {{161, 387}, {200, 49}}
content: {{0, 9}, {200, 40}}
arrow: {{87, 0}, {19, 9}}
```

What is happening there? I tried almost all content modes or whatever. `autoresizeSubviews` on all views is turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the rotation, call `CGRectIntegral` on the frames of the view(s) in question.

The reason for the problem is that you are ending up between pixels so everything is being aliased. This typically happens when e.g. a view is centered.

A quick way to confirm this has happened in the Simulator is to check Debug > Color Misaligned Images. If those images are colored, then yes, they are misaligned: they are not being drawn at integral pixel coordinates.

Comment: I'm walking in circles now. Arrow can change its x position (and it'll have a fraction part) and `CGRectIntegral` can (and will) enlarge it and there'll be white intersection of arrow and button. But if I call `sizeToFit` or set its size to size before calling this function or even call `round` on the float x coordinate your method won't work at all because `CGRectIntegral` will do nothing with this `CGRect`.

Comment: I have explained the source of the problem (fractional point amounts mapped onto integral screen pixels). It is up to you to use autoresizing or autolayout or manual layout (`layoutSubviews`) to prevent the side effects you are objecting to. You have withheld your code that draws this stuff, so I can't tell you any further specifics.

Comment: Thx for your update, helped me a lot. Because this view is very deep in the hierarchy, my solution was to get view's coordinate in the main window and calculate a diff between `round`ed coord and initial and then apply it to the coordinate in the superview's `bounds` (then it became fractional). And it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you count the height of the arrow, before rotation it is 18px in height and after rotation it is 19 pixels in height.

So when you scale, what happens it is anti-aliased and creates that grey line. So there are a couple of ways you could go about doing it. Here is a great post about resizing the right way:

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Hope it helps.